# Not able to publish the ASP.NET Core Web API in development environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. Now I publish the application from Visual Studio 2022. After publishing the project, when I run the exe file it is always shows the Production environment.

To check it I added log:

```
Log.Logger.Information($"App-start {builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}");
```

But I want to publish it in the `Development` environment.

`Program.cs` file:

```
using Serilog;
using Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string _CorsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
IocConfigurator.RegisterIoc(builder.Services);
Log.Logger.Information($"App-start {builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}");
Console.WriteLine($"App-start {builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}");
// Configuration setup
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath)
    //.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

var allowedOrigins = configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Value?.Split(",") ?? new string[] { "*" };

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(_CorsPolicy,
        builder => builder
        .WithOrigins(allowedOrigins)
        .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(5))
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});

// Set up configuration in DI
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);

//Add support to logging with SERILOG
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) =>
    configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//Add support to logging request with SERILOG
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

app.UseCors(_CorsPolicy);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`launchsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5122"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "FTHelp - Dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7034;http://localhost:5122"
    },
    "FTHelp - Test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Test"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7035;http://localhost:5122"
    },
    "FTHelp - Prod": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7035;http://localhost:5122"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:24747",
      "sslPort": 44359
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi sandanuwan, could you share an update on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should [set environment variable in your machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#windows---set-environment-variable-globally).

There are many ways you can choose.

1. [Windows - IIS deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#windows---iis-deployments)
2. [Windows - Set environment variable globally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#windows---set-environment-variable-globally)